# Romney claims that China likes to "flaunt the rules"

Tags: meaning

In last night's GOP debate, candidate Mitt Romney implied that China tends to "flaunt the rules".  Looking up "flaunt," it means to "show off."

So what did he mean?

Comment: From Google: http://www.word-detective.com/2011/03/03/flout-flaunt/

Comment: That's just Romney flouting his education.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

He meant *flout*, but this is apparently a really common mistake [(Google Ngram):](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flaunt+the+rules%2Cflout+the+rules&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

[image: Google Books Ngram comparing usage of "flaunt the rules" and "flout the rules"]

> [Flout](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flout): to treat with contemptuous disregard : scorn (flouting the rules) [Merriam-Webster]

Comment: +1. *Flout* is definitely the word. It is really unfortunate that such a mistake can be made at such a high-profile level.

Comment: Is this really that terrible a crime against English? Some of the connotations *are* in the ballpark. For instance, "flaunt" has the sense of doing something *defiantly*, etc. (A linked article in the comments on the question even indicates these might have been the same word at some point...)

Comment: I think you are being rather harsh Jimi. These guys (and gal) speak tens of thousands of words each day, goofs are inevitable, and, as gaffs go this is a tiny one. Verbal flubs are a bipartisan (or multi-partisan) affliction. Biden and Bush are both legendary for their flubbiness.

Comment: @Fraser and Joe: Sorry if I came across as harsh. Indeed, *flaunt* kind of makes sense. I mean, the error is not really a big deal, as it's something that's widely accepted. English is evolving constantly, and that includes the legitimization of common errors. No BD again. That's just life. Mine was just a very offhand comment. Take it as you will :)

Comment: I suppose they could be said to be flaunting their flouting of the rules !

Comment: @JOe: "It's a terrible crime against English" for someone running for President of the United States. Whole wars have been started by mispelled/misplaced words, or even commas in diplomatic documents.